# Is file accessing process from asset folder the same as, accessing a file from external storage

Tags: android, file, file-io

I have a method in my code which takes **path of a folder** as an argument. When I am using SD card I can simply give the path, but can I do the same with asset, and if so how? I need to write `File f=new File(path)` so that I can give `f.getabsoultepath()` as my argument. so what should be the value of **path**  lets assume this is how my asset folder is orginzed and **arc** is my folder [image]

Comment: what I don't get the most is every resource I read about asset reads the file using input stream,and none of them show how to acess folders(directories) which have files in them.

Comment: The File class is of no use for assets. Indeed getAssets().open() will open an inputstream. That opens a file in a folder too. You can also list the files in a folder.